# Does the use of sunscreen inhibit Vitamin D production?

Tags: vitamin-d, uv-rays, sun-exposure, sunlight, sunscreen-sunblock

Vitamin D is produced in the skin when exposed to sunlight.
Therefore, when using sunscreen on the skin, is Vitamin D production inhibited?

Comment: Excellent question!  Love seeing this kind of Q here :)  I edited it slightly to add the sun-skin-VitD mechanism you were indirectly referring to, which is more in line with question guidelines.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: Where are the twitter feed bots when you need them? +1 excellent question indeed.

Comment: May I add to the question: If  yes ( i.e. sunscreen block vitamin D production) , so what are healthy ways to substitue this blockage and get the production of vitamin D?

Answer (score 5):

This has been a [controversial question for many years](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2009/02/17/health/17real.html?referer=). The current evidence suggests that sunscreen **does block a part of Vitamin D production, but with negligible amounts**.

> Studies have found that by blocking ultraviolet rays, sunscreen limits
>   the vitamin D we produce. But the question is to what extent.
>
> A few studies have concluded that the effect is significant — a
>   reduction as great as tenfold. But more recent, **randomized studies
>   that followed people for months and in some cases years suggest that
>   the effect is negligible.** While sunscreen does hamper vitamin D
>   production, these studies say, it is not enough to cause a deficiency.
>   *[...]*
>   Dr. Lim added that **rather than cutting back on sunscreen**, people
>   concerned about vitamin D should **consume more foods rich in vitamin D**,
>   like salmon, milk and orange juice.
>
> *Source: [New York Times Article](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2009/02/17/health/17real.html?referer=), Emphasis Mine*

---

### Studies cited in the article

- Matusoka LY et al. *Chronic sunscreen use decreases circulating concentrations of 25-hydroxyvitamin D. A preliminary study.*      [PubMed link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/3190255/)
- Marks R et al. *The effect of regular sunscreen use on vitamin D levels in an Australian population. Results of a randomized controlled trial.* [PubMed link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/7726582/)
- Farrerons J et al. *Clinically prescribed sunscreen (sun protection factor 15) does not decrease serum vitamin D concentration sufficiently either to induce changes in parathyroid function or in metabolic markers.* [PubMed link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/9767286/)

Answer (score 4):

Vitamin D is produced in the skin. There are two subtypes of UV radiation: UVA and UVB. UVA is primarily responsible for photoaging, and UVB for the superficial burning that results from sun exposure (2).

UVB electromagnetic radiation converts 7-dehydrocholestrol to pre-vitamin D3, which is then converted into Vitamin D3 (1). Sunscreens with an SPF rating absorb or reflect (depending on the filters used) UVB light (2). Without UVB light, 7-dehydrocholestrol cannot be converted into pre-vitamin D. It may also be of interest to note that glass blocks UVB (but not UVA radiation) and thus has a similar effect on Vitamin D production (1).

In reality, however, people rarely apply sunscreen well enough so that Vitamin D production completely ceases (3).

In short, yes sunscreen does inhibit the production of Vitamin D, although in most cases not to such an extent that Vitamin D deficiency becomes a concern.

**References**

1. https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminD-HealthProfessional/
2. http://www.skincancer.org/prevention/uva-and-uvb
3. https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/6-things-you-should-know-about-vitamin-d

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers:

> [C]linical studies have never found that everyday sunscreen use leads to
> vitamin D insufficiency. In fact, the prevailing studies show that
> people who use sunscreen daily can maintain their vitamin D levels.
>
> One of the explanations for this may be that no matter how much
> sunscreen you use or how high the SPF, some of the sun’s UV rays reach
> your skin. An SPF 15 sunscreen filters out 93 percent of UVB rays, SPF
> 30 keeps out 97 percent, and SPF 50 filters out 98 percent. This
> leaves anywhere from 2 to 7 percent of solar UVB reaching your skin,
> even with high-SPF sunscreens. And that’s if you use them perfectly.

[Sun Protection and Vitamin D By Skin Cancer Foundation](https://www.skincancer.org/blog/sun-protection-and-vitamin-d/)

> There are claims that one needs to get a certain amount of sun
> exposure every day in order to produce enough vitamin D to be healthy.
> It’s just not true
>
> *David J. Leffell, MD, Yale Medicine dermatologist and chief of
> Dermatologic Surgery*

[Vitamin D Myths 'D'-bunked - Yale Medicine](https://www.yalemedicine.org/stories/vitamin-d-myths-debunked/)

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/16586/7951